# Unity 5 import - Shader changed to Standard from Diffuse

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I am loading 3d models (fbx) as assetbundles in my Unity Windows app. I am trying to upgrade my Unity 4.3 project to Unity 5.2.1. I am seeing a color difference in the models in Unity 5. They are darker than the previous version.

When I compared the two versions, it looks that the objects that had the Shader as Diffuse in 4.3 now coming as Standard in the 5.2. I guess this is happening when importing the model (when creating the asset bundle).

Please let me know how I can fix this issue. I have hundreds of models that I am importing to Unity 5.2. So manually changing them is not an option.

I have attached a sample to show the color difference.

[image]
[image]

Thanks